# Group array object by category id using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to group my array by Id in jQuery, Here are the details of my code and what I am trying to achieve.

```
var result = Array[5] // array of 5 records
Array[0]: 
   Description: "Testing Desc1"
   CategoryName: "Fruit"
   CategoryId : 1
   Title: "Data1"
Array[1]: 
   Description: "Testing Desc2"
   CategoryName: "Veg"
   CategoryId : 2
   Title: "Data2"
Array[2]: 
   Description: "Testing Desc3"
   CategoryName: "Fruit"
   CategoryId : 1
   Title: "Data3"
Array[3]: 
   Description: "Testing Desc4"
   CategoryName: "Grains"
   CategoryId : 3
   Title: "Data4"
Array[4]: 
   Description: "Testing Desc5"
   CategoryName: "Grains"
   CategoryId : 3
   Title: "Data5"
```

Each record has some categoryId in it which can be same for some of records, I need to group array on basis of category id and create a new json array.

My Required output is like this:

```
var data = [{
    Category: "Fruit",
    Data: [{
        Title: "Data1",
        Description: "Testing Desc1"
    }, {
        Title: "Data3",
        Description: "Testing Desc3"
    }]
}, {
    Category: "Veg",
    Data: [{
        Title: "Data2",
        Description: "Testing Desc2"
    }]
}, {
    Category: "Grains",
Data: [{
        Title: "Data4",
        Description: "Testing Desc4"
    }, {
        Title: "Data5",
        Description: "Testing Desc5"
    }]
}];
```

Please help!

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Also your object and result don't line up... `CategoryName` fruit is data1 and data3, and in the result fruit is data1 and data2, also veg is data2 and then turns into data3...and same with grains not lining up...? Is this an intended pattern?

Comment: Your input isn't any sort of valid array, so I can't tell you how to transform it into your required input.  You'll need to show what your input is before anyone can help you rearrange it into what you need.

Comment: Input edited with correct values, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you are dealing with an array of objects - use the following approach with `Array.forEach` and `Object.keys` functions:

```js
    var result = [
        {
            Description: "Testing Desc1",
            CategoryName: "Fruit",
            CategoryId: 1,
            Title: "Data1"},
        {
            Description: "Testing Desc2",
            CategoryName: "Veg",
            CategoryId: 2,
            Title: "Data2"},
        {
            Description: "Testing Desc3",
            CategoryName: "Fruit",
            CategoryId: 1,
            Title: "Data3"},
        {
            Description: "Testing Desc4",
            CategoryName: "Grains",
            CategoryId: 3,
            Title: "Data4"},
        {
            Description: "Testing Desc5",
            CategoryName: "Grains",
            CategoryId: 3,
            Title: "Data5"
        }
    ],
            groups = {};
    
    result.forEach(function (o){
        var dataObj = {Title: o.Title, Description: o.Description};
        if (groups[o.CategoryId]) {
            groups[o.CategoryId]['Data'].push(dataObj);
        } else {
            groups[o.CategoryId] = {Category: o.CategoryName, Data: [dataObj]};
        }
    });
    var data = Object.keys(groups).map(function(k) { return groups[k]; });
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4));
```

Comment: it worked like a charm... thanks a ton... you saved my day ......... :)

Comment: @DeepikaThakur, welcome, have you tried to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is based on [Array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var data = [{
  Description: "Testing Desc1",
  CategoryName: "Fruit",
  CategoryId: 1,
  Title: "Data1"
}, {
  Description: "Testing Desc2",
  CategoryName: "Veg",
  CategoryId: 2,
  Title: "Data2"
}, {
  Description: "Testing Desc3",
  CategoryName: "Fruit",
  CategoryId: 1,
  Title: "Data3"
}, {
  Description: "Testing Desc4",
  CategoryName: "Grains",
  CategoryId: 3,
  Title: "Data4"
}, {
  Description: "Testing Desc5",
  CategoryName: "Grains",
  CategoryId: 3,
  Title: "Data5"
}];


var result = data.sort((a, b) => {return a.CategoryName.localeCompare(b.CategoryName);}).reduce(function(a,b,c) {
  if (c == 1) {
    if (a.CategoryName == b.CategoryName) {
      return [{
        Category: a.CategoryName,
        Data: [{
          Title: a.Title,
          Description: a.Description
        }, {
          Title: b.Title,
          Description: b.Description
        }]
      }];
    } else {
      return [{
        Category: a.CategoryName,
        Data: [{
          Title: a.Title,
          Description: a.Description
        }]
      }, {
        Category: b.CategoryName,
        Data: [{
          Title: b.Title,
          Description: b.Description
        }]
      }];
    }
  } else {
    if (a[a.length - 1].Category == b.CategoryName) {
      a[a.length - 1].Data.push({
        Title: b.Title,
        Description: b.Description
      });
    } else {
      a.push({
        Category: b.CategoryName,
        Data: [{
          Title: b.Title,
          Description: b.Description
        }]
      });
    }
    return a;
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```